# Аналог top под Windows

Tags: windows, perl

Необходимо следить за некоторыми процессами (время работы, потребление ресурсов и пр.) из Perl-скрипта. Не могу сообразить, как бы это правильно сделать в Windows?

UPS: Система - х64, на которую часть модулей с cpan не устанавливается (как правило, о этом можно судить по отчетам, из моей практики - 100% совпадение).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Рекомендую использовать утилиты из коллекции SysInternals.http://technet.microsoft.com/sysinternalsВ частности, для просмотра процессов предназначена утилита pslist, а для принудительного завершения процесса pskill.

Comment: Спасибо! Похоже, что это даже лучше, чем я рассчитывал найти!

Answer (score 1):

`GUI: taskmgr.exe` - сами можете настроить нужные столбцы для отображения в окне процессов.

`console: tasklist.exe` - параметрами командной строки можно некоторые настройки выставить. для более гибкого отображения придется писать батник с использованием конвейеров.

Ну убить приложение можно командой `taskkill.exe`

Comment: Спасибо, tasklist вполне подойдет. PS: Для запуска, приостановки (suspend) и завершения процессов есть хорошие Perl-модули, типа Win32::Proccess или его аналоги. Ну и не батник, а perl-скрипт, но это уже детали. Главное, что утилита подходит :)

Comment: не люблю перл, это все никсовое =) В винде есть powershell он заменяет своей навороченностью все что нужно для администратора и написания всяческих скриптов для автоматизации. PS: в PowerShell получение списка процессов делается Get-Process =)

Comment: У нас рабочие станции работают как под Linux, так и под Windows и MacOS. Так что, выбор языка вполне оправдан.

Answer (score 0):

Я в perl вообще ни как, вот в поиске [нашёл](http://sskript.at.ua/news/kontrol_za_processami/2009-12-16-67):

> Если приложение не оставляет никакихфайлов, то остается только один выход- узнать, существует ли в данный момент идентификатор процесса.Получить его можно с помощьюстандартных утилит ps, grep и awk.Само выделение идентификатора оченьполезно - с ним можно сделать многовещей - например, послать сигналSIGINT (rehash). Таким образом,промодифицируем скрипт.
>
> ```
> #!/usr/bin/perl  chomp($cmd=`ps ax|grep pppd|grep -v grep|awk \'{print$1}\'`);  unless($cmd) { system(\"/sbin/service pptptunnelstart\");  }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

perfmon.exe не консольная, но это же windows ))

Comment: всё рождено из консоли :)